# C# Xamarin Can't find .apk after exporting ("aapt.exe" exited with code 1)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, apk

Today i tried to export my android ap as .apk
[image: settings]

after clicking export android package it says "Building Android Package..." below and if i wait a little it says ready.
But if i go to Projectfolder/bin/Release i can't find my apk...
What could be the cause of that? It worked for me earlier,

In the Release folder there are only these files:
[image: Files in release folder after exporting]

Thanks.

EDIT:
After cleaning the solution and exporting again, i got some more files but still no .apk

[image: after clean]

EDIT:
I finally found a solution! Before i say anything i want to thank all of you (especially Jon Douglas) for taking your time and trying to fix my stupid mistake.

So the solution: i renamed my "app-icon.png" to "app_icon.png" ................ that's it

Comment: You should see the .APK there. Try to do a full solution clean and the export it again. Its working in my machine.

Comment: Cleaned the solution, exported again, now i got some more files but still no .apk :(

Comment: My apk appeared a fews seconds after all .dll generated. check it pease.

Comment: I did the last export about a hour ago, still no apk...

Comment: Try to create a brand new project and test it. If it happens its because of some problem with the apk generation. else, is something wrong with your project.

Comment: It worked with my other projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is silently failing in generating your `.apk`. You should look at your IDE logs found in `Help -> Xamarin -> Open Logs` and look at the latest `Ide.log`. You should then see messages such as the following for `Export Android Package (.apk)`: [image] which will ensure it worked. Once that happens you'll see the .apk in the `bin/Release` folder. [image]

I would also recommend using the newer option of `Tools -> Android -> Publish Android App` for a more well defined process in generating a signed `.apk`. You will then see a log such as the following: [image]

After this, it will generate in the same directory but also put the `aligned` package in the main directory by default(Based on the wizard):

[image]

[image]

Comment: And when using the other method it says "Packaging failed"

Comment: I think it may have somthing to do with me replacing the default icon maybe?

Comment: Where did you place the icon and what name it have?

Comment: @Ingmar05 I would suspect that your project doesn't even compile as it is failing at `"aapt.exe" exited with code 1` which typically means that a Resource in the pipeline is A) Named incorrectly (Try renaming it to a single lower case word, or use underscores) B) The resource is corrupt or saved as a different file type than it's expected. I would highly suggest you get the diagnostic build output to see where it's crashing exactly if you can.